# Mipoint between points in projective space

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

Is there a way to define the midpoint between points in projective space?

Comment: No, not if you want it to have any projective characterization. Indeed, the projective group acts transitively on the set of points of the line joining your two points (with them excluded)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by projective characterizartion?

Comment: I mean precisely what my second sentence says :-) All the points in the line joining your two points are indistinguisable from the point of view of projective geeometry.

Comment: So does it make sense to have a distance between two points in projective space?

Comment: Well, that depends on what properties exactly you want that 'distance' to have. If you want a distance which is projectively invariant, then no.

Comment: Think of $\mathbb{P}^1$ as the $2$-sphere $S^2$, and pick two antipodal points. What could their midpoint possibly be?

Answer (score 0):

You can map any three points on a line to any three other using a projective transformation. So there exists a projective transformation which fixes the two points you have but maps your supposed midpoint anywhere at all. Therefore there can be no definition of a midpoint which is invariant under projective transformations.

If you fix one hyperplane as the set of points at infinity, then you can use that to define a midpoint: The midpoint of $AB$ would be the point $M$ satisfying $\operatorname{CR}(A,B;F,M)=-1$ where $F$ is the point at infinity on the line $AB$.